# Android realtime location tracking for 3D model augmented reality

Tags: android, 3d, augmented-reality, location-based

I'm trying to implement a location-based AR solution similar to the GPS/Location tracking feature of Metaio Unifeye SDK (they stop support ARMv6 devices since their 2.5 version, but I must target those devices)

I want my users to be able to view a 10-meter high humanoid monster 3D Model in a 0.5 km radius area.
It must be a non-optical solution in which:
- Location (from GPS or Network provider) and compass will be used as reference for camera manipulation.
- Sensors may help estimating.

Is there any existing implementation (library or tutorial) for realtime location tracking sufficient for my requirement?

Comment: Hi, just wondering if you ever got anywhere with this?

Comment: It seems like nobody wants 10-meter high humanoid monsters to invade the world.